# Get values for a given key and its parent with jq

Tags: json, jq

I've got a JSON object like so:

```
{
  "1": {
    "available_memory": 1086419656.0,
    "available_memory_no_overbooking": 1086419656.0,
    "conns": 1.0
  },
  "2": {
    "available_memory": 108641236.0,
    "available_memory_no_overbooking": 10861216.0,
    "conns": 2.0
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve the value of "conns" atribute for each object id. I am new at jq and I cant found clear examples.

I have tried the following:

```
echo "$OUTPUT" | jq -r .[].conns
```

Which returns all the values for conns, but thats is not what I needed. The spected output would be:

```
1 1.0
2 2.0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no array in the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k) \(.[$k].conns)"' file.json
1 1
2 2
```

Seems like jq translates 1.0 to 1 and 2.0 to 2. Altering the input for clarity:

```
$ cat file.json
{
  "1a": {
    "available_memory": 1086419656.0,
    "available_memory_no_overbooking": 1086419656.0,
    "conns": 1.1
  },
  "2b": {
    "available_memory": 108641236.0,
    "available_memory_no_overbooking": 10861216.0,
    "conns": 2.2
  }
}
$ jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k) \(.[$k].conns)"' file.json
1a 1.1
2b 2.2
```

Refs:

- https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Variable/SymbolicBindingOperator:...as$identifier|...
- [https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-\(foo)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo))

Comment: Would this still work if some of the keys do not contain the corresponding attribute (in this case `.conns`) or would it generate an error?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I do get an error (in particular "Cannot index number with string <stringname>": therefore my comment can be rephrased to how to specify the correct grammar to avoid it :)

Answer (score 0):

alternative solution *([`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc))* facilitates the ask with a bit of standard cli:

```
bash $ echo $OUTPUT | jtc -rl -w'[+0]' -w'[+0][conns]' | sed 's/: {.*//g; s/^"conns"://' | xargs -n2
1 1.0
2 2.0
bash $
```

jtc (unlike jq) is a utility which confines its functionality to json operations only (so its interface is drastically simpler), however manipulating articles outside of JSON data model is offloaded to external unix tools

EDIT: Newer version of `jtc` supports a simpler solution:

```
bash $ jtc -w'<conns>l:<con>v[-1]<key>k' -T '"{key} {con}"' -qq <<<$OUTPUT
1 1.0
2 2.0
bash $
```